# Can't update date field in Account from Opportunity trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I have an Apex trigger on `Opportunity` objects that is fired `after insert`. When the opportunity is inserted, I want to update a date-type field, `Pipeline_Start__c`, in the Account to which the Opportunity belongs to. The problem is that when I run my tests, the `Pipeline_Start__c` field is always null. Here is the trigger

```
trigger OpportunityTrigger on Opportunity (after insert) {
    List<String> emails = new List<String>();
    for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
        Account acc = [select PersonEmail from Account where id=:opp.AccountId];
        acc.Pipeline_Start__c = Date.today();
        update acc;
        emails.add(acc.PersonEmail);
    }
    InfusionSoftClient.AddTag(emails);
}
```

**Updating to show unit test**

```
@isTest
private static void TestCreateOpp() {
    Account acc = new Account(
        FirstName='FIRST',
        LastName='LAST',
        PersonEmail='test@testa.com',
    );
    insert acc;

    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCallOutMock.class, new CalloutMock());
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
        Name='PIPELINE',
        AccountID=acc.id,
    );
    insert opp;
    Test.stopTest();

    System.debug(acc); // Prints out Firstname, Lastname, PersonEmail and Id, NOT Pipeline_Start__c
    System.assertEquals(acc.Pipeline_Start__c, Date.today());
}
```

Comment: Never ever use a query in a for loop. Even if you haven't gotten to logic-less triggers, that's an absolute must to understand before pushing any triggers into a live environment. That said, we need to see your test before knowing why it fails.

Comment: Even if there can only be one result from the query?

Comment: The limit on query rows is not the governor you're worried about blowing up. It's the limit on queries. This one is really easy to pull outside the loop using `Map<Id, Account>([/*soql*/])`. You can cache a `Set<Id> accountIds` by iterating through `trigger.new` and pulling out each `AccountId`.

Comment: We'd need to see your unit test. My best guess is that you forgot to query the account back from the database.

Comment: @sfdcfox I have updated to show my unit test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-query the database. Also note that the syntax for assertions is to put the expected value first, then the actual value. You should also strongly consider adding informative assertion messages. They add a lot of value to your test suite.

```
...
Test.stopTest();

acc = [SELECT Pipeline_Start__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.Id];
system.assertEquals(Date.today(), acc.Pipeline_Start__c, 'Add some informative message');
```

Also note you have two separate governors which are going to explode if you operate on a collection. You query and update within a loop. You do not even need to query for records to update them if you already know their Id. You can change your code to the following and it will be much more bulk safe:

```
Date today = Date.today();
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
for (Opportunity record : trigger.new)
{
    if (record.AccountId != null)
    {
        accounts.put(record.AccountId, new Account(
            Id=record.AccountId, Pipeline_Start__c=today
        ));
    }
}
update accounts.values();
```